# Is there a trait or any convention to check if a range or a `view_facade` that owns things? (e.g. getlines)

Tags: c++, range, traits, range-v3

Given

```
auto empty_line = [](auto& str){ return str.size() == 0; };
```

For that fact that `ranges::getlines` returns an *owning* `view_facade` that owns a buffer for its frontal iterator.

So we are kind of obligated to make that kind of range an *lvalue* before passing to algorithms.

```
auto line_range1 = ranges::getlines(std::cin);
auto iter1 = ranges::find_if_not(line_range1,empty_line);
auto input1 = std::stoi(*iter1);
```

And also there is a cool protection machanism preventing all dereferencing of iterators' at-time already destroyed data and make those attempt compile time errors.

So when an owning `view_facade` is passed into an algorithm as *rvalue*, the protection engages at the dereference.

This won't compile.

```
auto iter2 = ranges::find_if_not(ranges::getlines(std::cin),empty_line);
// at this point the `owning` range destroyed, 
// so as the buffer we (should've) hold (before!).

// So this won't compile
// auto input2 = std::stoi(*iter2);
```

Error as:

```
<source>:19:29: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'ranges::v3::dangling<ranges::v3::_basic_iterator_::basic_iterator<ranges::v3::getlines_range::cursor> >')
     auto input2 = std::stoi(*iter2);
                         ^~~~~~
```

This also won't compile either.

```
// Won't compile
// auto input3 = std::stoi(*ranges::find_if_not(ranges::getlines(std::cin),
//                                              empty_line)
//                        );
```

Error as:

```
<source>:22:29: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'ranges::v3::safe_iterator_t<ranges::v3::getlines_range> {aka ranges::v3::dangling<ranges::v3::_basic_iterator_::basic_iterator<ranges::v3::getlines_range::cursor> >}')
     auto input3 = std::stoi(*ranges::find_if_not(ranges::getlines(std::cin),empty_line));
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[godbolt.org/g/gF6nYx](https://godbolt.org/g/gF6nYx)

---

**My question is that other than documentation, is there any traits or any kind of range convention to check if a range type is *owning* ?**

Perhaps, something like `constexpr bool is_owning_v(Rng&&)`

Comment: Is std::ranges::borrowed_range what you're looking for?

Comment: @mmackliet I guess that borrowed_range "concept" represents non-owning model like one in string_view and span. Of course, includes those in "views". So borrowed_range ranges can work as rvalue naturally, well like string_view, because someone somewhere already owns it as an lvalue before the use of borrowed_range.

Comment: @mmackliet In contrast, ranges::getlines do own a line in itself and can't use as rvalue iterator source as you see in the question.

Comment: @mmackliet One more thing, borrowed_range concept does include "std::is_lvalue_reference_v<R>". So this "borrowed_range" differs from string_view is that right after a range anchored as an lvalue itself, it's safe to return iterator from it, well because someone somewhere owns it before, in this case its lvalue.

Comment: @mmackliet  So ranges::getlines becomes borrowed_range right after you anchors it as an lvalue. In other word, right after ranges::getlines has its own variable name in a scope.

Comment: @mmackliet I guess the name of borrowed_range concept is kinda sketchy a bit here. In some sense, it contrasts against its own name!! 

Comment: Okay, then if std::ranges::enable_borrowed_range is false, wouldn't that mean that the type is an owning range?

Comment: @mmackliet Thank you. You're right. [LIVE](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/v9ejfKWsf) From [P2017R1](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p2017r1.html) borrowed_range compliant range/view/adaptors must implement `enable_borrowed_range` [variable template](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/81b6d3f1bf636395645cc2ed245a5947c404a4b2/include/range/v3/view/drop_while.hpp#L81) to answer that "safe" property when used as an rvalue. That is the iterator will live on after the semicolon of the statement of the range/view.

Comment: For further reading [P2017R1](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p2017r1.html) seems to clearify this topic pretty well. Thank again @mmackliet

Comment: Awesome. I added an answer summarizing our comments

Answer (score 1):

std::ranges::enable_borrowed_range will tell you if range type is **NOT** owning. See [P2017R1](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p2017r1.html). To implement the function you described, you could do so like this:

```
template <typename Rng>
constexpr bool is_owning_v(Rng&&)
{
  return !std::ranges::enable_borrowed_range<std::remove_cvref_t<Rng>>;
}
```